# Best practice for xml service response error handling

Tags: c#, xml, api

I'm working on our system integration with some xml service and I would like to know are there any best practices to handle responses that represent errors.
E.g. I have a request:

```
<FindSmthPls>
   <Login>MyLogin</Login>
   <Password>MyPassword</Password>
   <SomeAttributes>...</SomeAttribute>
</FindSmthPls>
```

And a response:

```
<FindSmthResponse>
   <SomeResults>...</SomeResults>
</FindSmthResponse>
```

But in case when xml service returns an error in the format:

```
<Error>
  <ErrorCode>1</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorMessage>Sorry but we cannot find anything for your request!</ErrorMessage>
</Error>
```

I can not deserialize that xml into **FindSmthResponse** that's why I have to handle errors in the next ways:

```
    try 
    {
        return Deserialize<T>(xml);
    }
    //for the cases when I cannot deserialize response
    //I can assume that service returned an error
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        var error = Deserialize<TError>(xml);
        throw new XmlException(error);
    }
```

But as you can see from my Error response example above not all errors are bad, some of them  just says that there is nothing to return. That's why in a place where I handle this error I should add smth like that:

```
    catch (XmlException e)
    {
        //workaround for cases when service returns errors like: result is empty
        if (_safeErrors.Any(c => 
            c.Key.Equals(e.XmlError.Code, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && 
            c.Value.Equals(e.XmlError.Message, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
        {
            return null;
        }

        throw new XmlApiException(e);
    }
```

In this solution at least two minuses:

1. We have some logic in error handler
2. We should match error codes and sometimes messages with a "errors white list" that allows us return just NULL and do not throw an exception in case when there is just nothing to return.

Of course this solution works but I really want to know maybe there are some best practices how we can handle different xml responses for the single xml request?

p.s. please note that XML service that I'm integrating with could return an error with code 1 as for real exception like: wrong login and for empty search result.

Comment: Is this an HTTP service? If so, I would prefer to rely on HTTP status codes to convey response format.

Comment: Yeah it's a good idea, and I would recommend to all developers return an HTTP code 500 for the errors, but in my case service return error in XML with HTTP code 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
<FindSmthResponse>
   <Header>
      <Errors>
          <Error>
              <Code>0</Code>
              <Detail>Success</Detail>
          </Error>
      </Errors>
   </Header>
   <SomeResults>...</SomeResults>
</FindSmthResponse>
```

You can even create the header definition as it's own xsd if you are using them and it can then be used across any of your services. Just have your element extend the service header and then when you are looking you can deserialize the entire thing and then check if there are errors in a different part of your logic.